# Weird image distortion in some browsers (TV effect)

Tags: css, browser

A customer just sent me a screenshot of a weird image distortion that he says is appearing on [my website](https://whitepayments.com):

[image: Weird image distortion]

Any ideas as to what might be causing this? He says he tried Chrome and Firefox, and they both had the same problem. I was unable to reproduce it on my machine.

Comment: Virus, or damaged graphic card, maybe? :)

Comment: @nevermind: why just my site :(

Comment: I looks like client problem.